# Multi-objective optimization with known variable dependencies (via a graph) -- what is this called?

Tags: constraint-programming, graphs, multi-objective-optimization

Suppose that I am trying to solve a standard multi-objective optimization problem:

$$
    \min_{
    \begin{array}{c}
        \textbf{x} \in S
    \end{array}
    }
    \left [ f_1(\textbf{x}),f_2(\textbf{x}),\ldots,f_m(\textbf{x}) \right ]
$$
where $\textbf{x}$ has to satisfy the constraints in $S$. Let us define these as:

$$
    S = \left \{ \textbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^d:
        \begin{aligned}
            g_i (\textbf{x}) &= c_i \text{ for } i=1,\ldots,k_j \\
            h_j (\textbf{x}) &\geq c_j \text{ for } i=1,\ldots,k_h
        \end{aligned}
        \right \}.
$$

But in addition, suppose I also know the variable dependency structure amongst the variables in $\textbf{x}$ via a directed graph.

Here's an example:

### [image: Variable dependencies.]

In this instance, I know that e.g. $x_2$ does not affect the response $f_1$ directly but rather via $x_1$. Similar for $x_3$ and $f_2$.

My two questions are:

1. Would I be better off encoding my graphical constraints as 'normal' constraints as found in $S$ or are there other methods for dealing with this type of 'extra' information?
2. What sort of methods could one use to deal with this type of problem? Clearly, we are looking for a Pareto optimal solution but we have this extra graphical information? $\textbf{x}$ can be either continuous or discrete it doesn't really matter, but the knowledge of the graph matters. I think it can be construed as a [constraint satisfaction problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem) (CSP) but I cannot seem to find a version of CSP which deals with directed graphs.

Any advice would be most welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe there is something I don't get here, but isn't the information you graphically represent already captured by the fact that some variables are present in one objective function and not in others?

Comment: Well I'm not sure but I don't think so. The constraints don't tell us about how the variables are dependent only what domain they need to be in to be a valid solution for the problem. But I could be wrong but I don't see how presently we can say that x2 is the parent of x1 in the constraints.

Comment: But what does it mean, that $x_2$ affect $x_1$? Isn't this expressed as constraints?

Comment: Well I'm not sure is what this questions boils down to I think. The constraints as I see them only specify that allowed search domains per variable. But they don't tell us anything about inter-variable dependency - which may be important information for the solution.

Comment: you state your constraints  as $g_i(\mathbf{x}) =c_i$ and $h_j(\mathbf{x}) \leq c_j$. If for instance $g_i(\mathbf{x})=x_1-x_2$ and $c_i=-1$ for some $i$, then you have stated the relation that $x_2$ must be one unit larger than $x_1$. So, in your definition of $S$ you have quite a lot more modeling power than just stating the domain of the variables.

Comment: That's a fair point, so perhaps that's it then: topological constraints in the graph can readily be converted one-to-one into algebraic expressions in $S$.

Comment: Yes. And if you can formulate your problem such that only a few variables "interact" with each other in each constraint, then you will end up with a very sparse constraint matrix, which is usually a good thing.

Comment: Okay that's interesting, is there a particular nomenclature one could/should google for that studies optimization problems with 'interacting variables' the way we've discussed in the comments? Naturally, I have focused on interaction through a graph but that's just one way of looking at it.

Comment: Turns out this falls under _partially separable_ optimization: https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/77032804.pdf